# How can I show ONLY the date (and not the time) using NSDateFormatter?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I think the question is pretty straightforward. I need only the date to appear, and not the time. Couldn't find anything for Swift, so my code is here:

```
cell.date.text = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(dates[indexPath.row],
        dateStyle: .ShortStyle,
        timeStyle: .ShortStyle)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: @"en_US")
let d = NSDate()
let s = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation of the method you are calling. There are four or five different possible values that you can pass for the formatting style of the date and the time. You picked a formatting style that outputs a short format. Pick instead the formatting style that does what you want. I'll give you a hint: There is one style with a "No" in the name.

Seriously, right click on "ShortStyle", and pick "Jump to Definition" from the popup menu.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let d = NSDate()
cell.date.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(d)
```